# Combined visualization of s(x) + s(y) + ti(x,y) smooths in R when using mgcv package to run a GAM

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I have generally run 2-D GAM smooths in R using `mgcv` with a tensor smooth `te()`:

```r
library(mgcv)
library(mgcViz)

m = gam(z~te(x,y),data=df)

gv = getViz(m)
plot(gv)
```

This produces a 2-D map of the combined effect of `x` and `y` on `z`.

However, I have recently discovered that using a tensor interaction term with single variable smooths produces a better fit for my data:

```r
library(mgcv)
library(mgcViz)

m = gam(z~s(x) + s(y) + ti(x,y),data=df)

gv = getViz(m)
plot(gv)
```

The problem with this is that this produces a visualization for `x` and for `y` and for the interaction of `x` and `y`, which is useful for diagnostics, but for producing a publication quality graph I would like to combine these marginal effects into a single graph as produced when I modeled using `te()`. Is there an easy way to do this? Is there a particularly strong argument for not combining these effects for visualization purposes?

Thanks!

## SOLUTION

Based on comments by [@gavin-simpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429846/gavin-simpson), I have developed a solution using `mgcv::vis.gam`. My actual model was somewhat more complicated than the model presented above in that it was in geographic lon,lat coordinates and stratified by quarter of the year. I also wanted to place a map of the world on top of the effect plot.

A simplified form of the model is:

```r
m = gam(z~s(lon,by=quarter) + s(lat,by=quarter) + 
      ti(lon,lat,by=quarter),data=df)
```

I plotted the lon,lat effect using this function:

```r
my_plot_gam_geo_quarter = 
  function(model,quarter,lon.lat=c("lon","lat"),contour.col="black",
           too.far=0.1,asp=1,
           world.col="lightgray",world.border="darkgray",
           cond=list(quarter=quarter)) {
    # Get world map from tmap package
    suppressWarnings(data("World",package="tmap",overwrite=FALSE))
    
    mgcv::vis.gam(model,view=lon.lat,cond=cond,plot.type="contour",
                  contour.col=contour.col,too.far=too.far,asp=asp)
    plot(World[1],add=TRUE,col=world.col,border=world.border) 
  }
```

With this function, I plotted the lon,lat effect for the first quarter of year as:

```r
my_plot_gam_geo_quarter(m,1)
```

Comment: I don't think it can't fit your data better; that it does is only an illusion formed by the fact that the decomposed (your second) model contain many more basis functions than the first model. Give the `te()` tensor product smooth more basis functions and it should do better than the decomposed model even only if it has fewer smoothing parameters to estimate. Anyway, unless you are wedded to ggplot graphics, see `mgcv::vis.gam` to plot the fit from all three smooths

Comment: I don’t think it *can* fit your data better…

Comment: I have looked around the web a bit and it seems like there is not much clarity on whether it fits better or not. Some say it can't and then others say it does. The mgcv documentation says that the ti() model will be more stable than the te() because of additional regularization parameters, so something does change, but not sure how that affects the fit. In any case, I have given the same k parameters to te and s+ti and the AIC of the model with ti is significantly lower than the AIC with te.

Comment: And yes `mgcv::vis.gam` does seem to be what I want. The only problem is that I was using some `mgcViz` tricks to add a world map onto the effects plot, but I seem to have found a solution to that. I will post something once I have figured it out.

Comment: Where does the mgcv documentation say that for `ti()` terms? Genuinely interested as I'd always observed that all else equal (sufficient basis dimensions in both models to make the `ti` and `te` forms similarly complex in terms of basis functions) the `ti` form would do no better than the `te` form and potentially worse as you now had to select an extra set of smoothing parameters. How did you set `k` to make the models equivalent?

Comment: It took me a while to find it, but it was in `?smooth.terms` in the paragraph on `ti`: `ti` smooths exclude the basis functions associated with the ‘main effects’ of the marginal smooths, plus interactions other than the highest order specified. These provide a stable an interpretable way of specifying models with main effects and interactions.... A similar construction involving `te` terms instead will be much less statsitically stable.

Comment: But that last sentence may be specifically referring to converting `te()` into `ti()` using some modeling tricks as opposed to `ti()` being generally more stable than `te()`. Hard to say...

Comment: Yeah, Simon means a formulation of `s(x1) + s(x2) + te(x1, x2)` would be much less stable because the marginal bases of the `te()` would be confounded with the bases for the two univariate smooths.

Comment: OK, thanks, this makes sense, but the text wasn't 100% clear. Someone recently told me that I was doing it wrong using te() instead of ti(), presumably because of that help page. You also asked about how I set k - I used the same single k value in all 3 terms, which would seem to me to be the correct approach, but admittedly it might be more as it corresponds to k*k + k + k instead of just k*k.